# Keycloak implementation in Typescript file index.tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, keycloak, keycloak-services

Keycloak implementation in Typescript file index.tsx

I'm trying to add keycloak in index.tsx but found an error . my landing page is layout.tsx I want to before keycloak login and after the login go to UI interface.
**Here is my index.tsx **

colud anyone help me how to implemented the keycloak in index.tsx and run on it for login page .

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createHashRouter, Router, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/react";
import  KeycloakUserService from "./components/Login/KeycloakUserService";
import "./index.css";

import Layout from "./pages/layout/Layout";
import Chat from "./pages/chat/Chat";

initializeIcons();

const router = createHashRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Layout />,
        children: [
            {
                index: true,
                element: <Chat />
            },
            {
                path: "qa",
                lazy: () => import("./pages/oneshot/OneShot")
            },
            {
                path: "*",
                lazy: () => import("./pages/NoPage")
            }
        ]
    }
    
]);
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
    
);

KeycloakUserService.initKeycloak(router);
```

**here is my keycloakservice.js and use for login purpose . **

```js
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

const keycloakJson = {
    "realm": "eMigration",
    "url": `https://1ansah.com/auth/`,
    "ssl-required": "none",
    // "clientId": process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_RESOURCE,
    // "resource": process.env.REACT_APP_KEYCLOAK_RESOURCE,
    "public-client": true,
    "confidential-port": 0
}

const _kc = new Keycloak(keycloakJson);
// const _kc: KeycloakInstance = Keycloak(keycloakJson);

/**
 * Initializes Keycloak instance and calls the provided callback function if successfully authenticated.
 *
 * @param onAuthenticatedCallback
 */
const initKeycloak = (onAuthenticatedCallback) => {
    _kc
        .init({
            onLoad: "login-required",
            silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + "/silent-check-sso.html",
            pkceMethod: "S256"
        })
        .then((_authenticated) => {
            onAuthenticatedCallback();
        })
        .catch(console.error);
};
const doLogin = _kc.login;

const doLogout = _kc.logout;

const getToken = () => _kc.token;

const getEmail = () => _kc.idTokenParsed.email;

const isLoggedIn = () => !!_kc.token;

const updateToken = (successCallback) => _kc.updateToken(5).then(successCallback).catch(doLogin);

const getUsername = () => _kc.tokenParsed?.preferred_username;

const hasRole = (roles) => roles.some((role) => _kc.hasRealmRole(role));

const getRoles = () => _kc.tokenParsed?.roles;

const getUserID = () => _kc.tokenParsed?.sub;

const isAuthenticated = () => _kc.authenticated;

const getGroups = () => _kc.tokenParsed?.groups;

const KeycloakUserService = {
    initKeycloak,
    doLogin,
    doLogout,
    getEmail,
    isLoggedIn,
    getToken,
    updateToken,
    getUsername,
    hasRole,
    getRoles,
    getUserID,
    isAuthenticated,
    getGroups
};

export default KeycloakUserService;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the app's content should only be rendered once authentication succeeds, you can surround it in a component that looks something like this:

```
// KeycloakAuth.tsx
import Keycloak, { KeycloakConfig } from 'keycloak-js'
import React, { FC, PropsWithChildren, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const initKeycloak = async (config: KeycloakConfig) => {
  const keycloak = new Keycloak(config)
  const authenticated = await keycloak.init({ /* ... */ })
  if (!authenticated) throw new Error('Authentication failed')
  return keycloak
}

type KeycloakContext = { keycloak: Keycloak }

const context = React.createContext<KeycloakContext|null>(null)
export const useKeycloak = () => {
  const value = useContext(context)
  if (!value) throw new Error('useKeycloak may only be used in a child element of KeycloakAuth')
  return value
}

type Props = PropsWithChildren<{
  config: KeycloakConfig
}>

export const KeycloakAuth: FC<Props> = props => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false)
  const [instance, setInstance] = useState<Keycloak|null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (instance) return
    initKeycloak(props.config)
      .then(
        keycloakInstance => {
          setInstance(keycloakInstance)
          setAuthenticated(true)
        },
        err => {
          // handle error
          console.error(err)
        }
      )
  }, [])

  return (authenticated && instance)
    ? <context.Provider value={{ keycloak: instance }}>
        {props.children}
      </context.Provider>
    : <SomeLoadingIndicator />
}
```

```
// index.tsx
// ...
  <KeycloakAuth config={keycloakConfig}>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </KeycloakAuth>
```

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ecstatic-allen-2hsqck?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.tsx%3A8%2C9) with an example setup. I've included a context hook for passing the Keycloak instance to any component. Copy the files you need, insert your keycloakJson, and host it on an origin permitted by the Client configuration.

Comment: I am facing some error on keycloakAuth.tsx. Could you send me hole code of this component with dummy instance ?

Comment: @sumitaRaj I added a CodeSandbox link to my answer. You'll have to put in the config yourself.

Comment: I am doing same but I am facing error    No route matches URL "state=60610e18-1592-4cfc-9943-351dd9092464&session_state=4c15a898-9c13-457b-9816-04e789c91f8e&code=f925a31f-58b6-4eb9-928a-22d9f67e340a.4c15a898-9c13-457b-9816-04e789c91f8e.ae31bcd9-c005-40f3-a250-07651b7769c2"

Comment: issue is resloved . could you tell me how to add logout ??

Comment: @sumitaRaj The Keycloak instance has a `logout` method. Check `App.tsx` in the CodeSandbox for an example.